# Why the txn_count is zero in the block message?

Tags: protocol, block

Why I'm receiving always zero in the txn_count field of the block message after calling it with a getdata ? Is this expected ? How can I get the transactions present in a block ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I was reading the Nonce from the block as a 64 bit integer like in the version message instead of a 32 bit integer.

Comment: great that you answered your own question, so that others can learn from this :-)